# How to install Telligent with sitecore 8.1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sitecore, forum, sitecore8, telligent

I want to install and configure telligent with sitecore 8.1. In Telligent documentation i don't know from where i should start installing the telligent, there are lots of process defined. can any one tell me the process to install telligent with sitecore 8.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that they are 2 different products so you need to first install both of them separately according to their own system requirements.  Generally Sitecore keeps this documentation here : https://dev.sitecore.net/

To install Telligent Community refer to here:
https://community.telligent.com/documentation/w/telligent-community-90/52408.install-telligent-community

Once that is done you have 2 ways to integrate:

1. REST Apis and Single Sign On Modules.  You could use the cookies auth module to do single sign on then you need to gather data from Telligent Community from its REST API.

community.telligent.com/training/w/developer90/52426.cookies-authentication#

community.telligent.com/training/w/developer90/52429.rest-api

2. The recommend way is the use the Telligent Community REST SDK which is still using REST but makes it easier and has some single sign on capabilities built in.  There is also some samples you can refer to.

community.telligent.com/training/w/developer90/52432.rest-sdk

github.com/Telligent/Community-Rest-SDK

github.com/Telligent/Social-SitecoreSDK-Samples

community.telligent.com/training/w/developer90/52432.rest-sdk

forgive the non-links, it will not let me post that many.

Comment: i am following 2nd approach and it's work fine for me. Thanks for your help!